# How to structure a query returning both a user's posts and the posts' categories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my controller's index action:

```
@posts = current_user.posts.process_and_return_posts
```

In the model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category

  def self.process_and_return_posts
    # doing some cleanup
    # return posts
  end
end
```

**In the view I will display the posts by category, I wonder how I should structure the query and in what type of collection I want the posts?**

I need the collection to contain both the Category objects and the Post objects (as I will order them when iterating over them in the view).

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you want is

```
group_by { |post| post.category }
```

This way you can use in your view

```
Post.process_and_return_posts.keys.each do |category|
  category.posts ...
end
```

This should also work in combination with your association

```
current_user.posts.process_and_return_posts.keys.each do |category|
  category.posts ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It's important to notice that `current_user.posts` actually returns Array object filled with Post objects, and **not** a post object.

So you should monkey patch `process_and_return_posts` method in Enumerable module instead of Post class.

You can monkey patch in many ways on Rails, but my favorite way is to put all the monkey patched code in one place, so that I know what's been monkey patched before.

From your rails directory, inside `config/initializers`, create a directory called `extensions`. This is where you can put all your monkey patched code. Inside `config/initializers/extensions`, create a Ruby file called, `enumerables.rb` so that you know later that this code contains code for enumerables.

In `config/initializers/extensions/enumerables.rb`,

```
module Enumerable
  def process_and_return_posts
    # your code here.
  end
end
```

Be sure to restart your rails server, whenever you update anything in `initializers`.